# Cómo puedo pasar tambien los espacios en blanco de un textarea a un div

Tags: javascript, html

El problema es que sólo se pasan las letras pero los espacios en blanco no se pasan al `div`, es decir, si dejo más de un espacio en blanco, solo se pasa como un solo espacio en blanco.

**Ejemplo**

Supongamos que se ingresa lo siguiente en el textarea: `hola      mundo`.

Pero, en el `div` solo se pasa de la siguiente manera: `hola mundo` 
(no pasa los espacios en blanco que se dejo entre la palabra `hola` y `mundo` dentro del textarea).

**Código:**

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea');
let div = document.querySelector('#div');

function funcionX(e) {
  div.innerHTML = e.target.value;
}

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', funcionX, false);
```

```css
.textarea,
.div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea" id="textarea" placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
<div class="div" id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Por regla general, en HTML todos los espacios en blanco, incluidos los saltos de línea, son reducidos a un sólo espacio en blanco.

Sin embargo para lograr lo que deseas puedes poner ese contenido dentro de una etiqueta `<pre>`.

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea');
let div = document.querySelector('#div');

function funcionX(e) {
  div.innerHTML = "<pre>"+e.target.value+"</pre>";
}

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', funcionX, false);
```

```css
.textarea,
.div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea" id="textarea" placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
<div class="div" id="div"></div>
```

---

[Referencia sobre la etiqueta `pre` de la W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Para  tu requerimiento sin necesidad de cambiar el jquery y complementando la información suministrada por el usuario @LeviArista te comento que existe la propiedad en css denominada ***white-space*** la cual según el valor que le asignes tratará a los espacios en blanco en una cadena de diferentes maneras como bien lo explica este enlace [white-space css](https://www.lawebera.es/xhtml-css/css-avanzado-propiedad-%E2%80%9Cwhite-space%E2%80%9D.php). ***Whitespace*** maneja diferentes valores pero de ellos nos conviene utilizar ***pre***.

Entonces para no cambiar tu código de javascript sencillamente agregas está propiedad a tus estilos css. Especificamente en este segmento de código:

```
.textarea,
.div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  white-space:pre <!-- Etiqueta que sirve para el control de espacios en blanco-->
}
```

De esta forma quedaría el código con el cambio que te comento para lograr justo lo que necesitas:

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea');
let div = document.querySelector('#div');

function funcionX(e) {
  div.innerHTML = e.target.value;
}

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', funcionX, false);
```

```css
.textarea,
.div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  white-space:pre
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textarea" id="textarea" placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
<div class="div" id="div"></div>
```

**Observación:** Puede que en algún momento desees eliminar los espacios en blanco en una misma línea y dejar exclusivamente los saltos de línea en una cadena de texto, para ello existe el valor denominado ***pre-line*** de la misma propiedad ***whitespace***. He aquí tu código con ***pre-line*** incluido:

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea');
let div = document.querySelector('#div');

function funcionX(e) {
  div.innerHTML = e.target.value;
}

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', funcionX, false);
```

```css
.textarea,
.div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  white-space:pre-line
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textarea" id="textarea" placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
<div class="div" id="div"></div>
```